# Create new columns from 2 row based on other columns with same date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe like

```
                          date item_id  type       amount
4538 2019-04-28 00:00:00+00:00      12     2  1050.200000
4539 2019-04-28 00:00:00+00:00      12     1    56.130000
4544 2019-04-29 00:00:00+00:00      12     2    30.588000
4545 2019-04-29 00:00:00+00:00      12     1    52.250000
4550 2019-04-30 00:00:00+00:00      12     2    27.010000
4551 2019-04-30 00:00:00+00:00      12     1    45.832910
4556 2019-05-01 00:00:00+00:00      12     2    22.040000
4557 2019-05-01 00:00:00+00:00      12     1  3756.617900
```

I want to merge data from 2 rows with same date and amount value of the row  which has type 1 will be assigned into new column named 'buy_amount', type 2 will be in 'sell_amount' column and omit the 'type', 'item_id' and the first index columns like this

```
                      date     buy_amount   sell_amount
 2019-04-28 00:00:00+00:00     56.130000    1050.200000
 2019-04-29 00:00:00+00:00     52.250000    30.588000
 2019-04-30 00:00:00+00:00     45.832910    27.010000
 2019-05-01 00:00:00+00:00     3756.617900  22.040000
```

Comment: Don't expect people to write code for you. Tell us (by editing your question) what you have done so far and why (what errors for example) it didn't work? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: have a look at `melt()`.

Comment: Sorry guys. It's just my first question, I did try to do it and searched the similar questions on stack but I didn't find anything. That's why I wrote this question. I will like what you guys suggested in the next questions. Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table` here and rename the columns:

```
df.pivot_table(index='date', values='amount', columns='type')\
  .rename({1:'buy_amount', 2:'sell_amount'}, axis=1)
```

---

```
type                       buy_amount  sell_amount
date                                              
2019-04-28 00:00:00+00:00    56.13000     1050.200
2019-04-29 00:00:00+00:00    52.25000       30.588
2019-04-30 00:00:00+00:00    45.83291       27.010
2019-05-01 00:00:00+00:00  3756.61790       22.040
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad I could help :) @Justin